# How to access a fab in host activity from fragment in Kotlin?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, kotlin, android-fragments

I want to acces the host main activity fab from another fragment and perform some action. How can I do this in Kotlin?

**MainActivity**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation"/>

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: from your fragment `requireActivity().yourFabReference`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Activity and cast it to your MainActivity type. The Activity is nullable because only part of the Fragment lifecycle overlaps with being attached to an Activity. Basically, don't access this in property declarations or from `lifecycleScope` unless using `lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted`.

Example:

```
val activityFab: FloatingActionButton
    get() = (activity as? MainActivity)?.binding?.fab ?: 
        error("Can only access if attached to MainActivity")
```

Just an example. For better encapsulation, you could expose a `fab` property from the MainActivity instead of the whole `binding`.